# How to use 2 Controller on 1 RequestMapping

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person/process")
public class A {
    //.....
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person/process")
public class B {
    //.....
}
```

Can I do that？Because there are too method in my controller,I want to have to separate them.

Comment: That makes no sense, which one should be called? It's the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the good design of your web application. Either you need to change the url mapping for both the controller by adding one more path after like */person/process/b* or you need to combine both classes and can have two separate methods serve as two different requests as per your need.

One more thing is you can separate them by specifying *RequestMethod* parameter in the *@RequestMapping* annotation on top of your controller classes.

But the way you have done same request mapping on top of your controllers will not successfully run your application as Spring Framework will throw exception for ambiguous mappings.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  You have to be able to distinguish between both mappings.  For example one method could be configured to consume json and another xml for example or a variation in a request parameter